# How can I get Javax.servlet.* classes in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, servlets, java

I am kinda a noob when it comes to interacting with servers. I have been using Eclipse for some time, but only now have I needed to utilize the javax.servlet.* classes. However, when I try to import these into the current class I am working with I get "The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved." I have tried following solutions found on other questions, but they don't seem to work for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have looked into the directory where my classes are.. I have javax.(stuff) but not javax.servlet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the Eclipse Web Development Tool plugin for your eclipse. check out here http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/development/ or go to

Help->Software updates->available softwares select web development tools

Answer (score 2):

Find where `java-serlvet.api` is and append it to your build classpath. For example, in Tomcat 6, it's in TOMCAT_DIR\lib, in Jetty 6 it's in JETTY_DIR\lib too.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the [web tools platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html) for Eclipse. [Download it from here](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/).